# Why @Autowired wires by class?

Tags: java, spring

If each bean has name, and we have [`getBean()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-) method, which receives bean name and in XML config we are also injecting beans by name, then why in Java config we are limited to `@Autowired` annotation which wires by class?

What is conventional way to inject beans into one configuration from another one? Is it possible to refer bean by name and not use `@Qualifier`?

**UPDATE**

I found a way to autowire by name between configurations.

First I autowire entire configuration by class:

```
@Autowired
MySeparateConfig mySeparateConfig;
```

Then I just call instantiation method from that bean:

```
@Bean
MyDependentBean myDependentBean() {
   MyDependentBean ans = new MyDependentBean();
   ans.setProperty( mySeparateConfig.myNamedBeanInDifferentConfig() );
   return ans;
}
```

Configs are of different classes by definition.

Comment: You don't have to use `@Autowired` for injection. You can define your beans in your _context.xml_ and let beans interact via `<property>` tags. _i.e._ `<property name="blabla" ref="blablaref">` inside bean definition tags.

Comment: @cihanseven your statement is correct still the question is why `@Autowire` defaults to by class when wiring the depency?

Comment: @Dims I don't think that you can autowire by name without `@Qualifier`

Comment: How many times do you have two beans of the same class but with different id?

Comment: @biziclop all the time

Comment: Autowiring by type is a convenient way for ensuring all the "building blocks" fit in together with no extra metadata (i.e. weakly typed qualifier strings). I'd argue that if you routinely find yourself creating many beans of the same type you may benefit from using profiles (hard to tell without knowing the reason)

Comment: @Dims It would be interesting to know why that happens, but autowiring definitely isn't for you then. In most cases I've come across, there is only one bean of a certain class.

Comment: @biziclop I am not looking for a wife, I am looking for understanding. If beans are always (or nearly allways) of different types, then why we are wiring by name in XML?

Comment: @Dims XML is the more ancient style of configuring Spring, that's all that existed originally. Then people realised that a lot of the XML config is redundant, full of `<bean id="Foo" class="com.foo.Foo"/>` type definitions, so when annotations were introduced to Java, autowiring was implemented to save much of that boilerplate config. XML config is still useful for cases where there is a genuine need to have multiple beans of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are several ways to inject bean by annotation.

given that we have this bean

```
<bean id="standardPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />
```

and in java class we can use following ways to inject it as far as I know

```
@Autowired  // by type
StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("standardPasswordEncoder")  // by bean id
StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;

javax.annotation.@Resource  // by bean id
StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;

javax.inject.@Inject  // by type
StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;
```

or use spEL

```
@Value(#{standardPasswordEncoder})  // by bean id
StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;
```

However, I don't know the reason why spring autowired default is by type, either, and also wondering why. I think it's dangerous to autowire by type. Hope this would help you.

Comment: *"it's dangerous to autowire by type"*? Any kind of autowiring that requires matching a string identifier (or worse, variable name) is more dangerous by making innocent refactorings potentially disastrous.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that javax.annotation.Resource is more dangerous. However, when it comes to spEL and Qualifier, I think it's much clearer that which bean is wired. It does not depend on variable name, but only on bean id. And it's less likely to get exceptions when there are beans with the same type.